# Send request on unload event

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, dom-events, use-effect

everyone. I got an array of objects with information about the event. For example:

```
"events": [
    ...,
    {
      "type": "unload",
      "listener": "/idempotency-session/end",
      "method": "post"
    }
  ]
```

I want to create eventListener from the information about this object.

```
const handleEvent = async (api, eventPayload) => {
            const {
                type,
                listener,
                method,
                action,
                headers = {},
                withParams = false,
            } = eventPayload;

            ...

            await callEndpoint(api, listener, method, {}, preparedHeaders)
                .then(data => { 
                    action && stateDispatch({ type: action, payload: data }); 
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        };

        useEffect(() => {  
            events && events.forEach((event) => {
                const handler = () => {
                    handleEvent(api, event);
                };
                
                window.addEventListener(event.type, handler, event.options);

                return () => {
                    window.removeEventListener(event.type, handler);
                };
            });

          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
          }, []);
```

**The problem: The request isn't sent on unload event (when a user closes the page or navigates to another). Also, I tried to use navigator.sendBeacon function, but it didn't help.**

Answer (score 1):

the question is how your dispatch your event ,
you should create event and dispatch it if they are in the same window scope your event run ,

```
const event  = new Event("onload",....)
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

second thing is your do it little bit wrong with react lifecycles you need to define 2 foreach

```
     useEffect(() => {  
            events && events.forEach((event) => {
                const handler = () => {
                    handleEvent(api, event);
                };
                
                window.addEventListener(event.type, handler, event.options);

               
            });


           return () => {
                events && events.forEach((event) => {
                    const handler = () => {
                        handleEvent(api, event);
                   };
                
                    window.addEventListener(event.type, handler, event.options);

               
            });
           };
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
          }, []);
```

and there is other problem when you remove your listener you should pass all params and you miss options

```
    window.removeEventListener(event.type, handler , event.options);
```

Comment: Thank you for the second and the third note. :) About the first one, I mean *upload* event, not *onload*. My main problem is that I can't send a request when a user closes the page or navigates from the page, even using the "navigator.sendBeacon" function.